# How to draw a regular polygon so that one edge is parallel to the X axis?

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, polygon

I know that to draw a regular polygon from a center point, you use something along the lines of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
    p.addPoint((int) (100 + 50 * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / n)),
               (int) (100 + 50 * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / n))
              );
}
```

However, is there anyway to change this code (without adding rotations ) to make sure that the polygon is always drawn so that the topmost or bottommost edge is parallel to a 180 degree line? For example, normally, the code above for a pentagon or a square (where n = 5 and 4 respectively) would produce something like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv6Xf.gif]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/or967.gif]

When what I'm looking for is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfxs1.gif] [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIORA.gif]

Is there any mathematical way to make this happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add `Pi/2-Pi/n`

```
k[n_] := Pi/2 - Pi/n;
f[n_] := Line[
   Table[50 {Cos[(2 i ) Pi/n + k[n]] ,Sin[(2 i) Pi/n + k[n]]}, {i,0,n}]];

GraphicsGrid@Partition[Graphics /@ Table[f[i], {i, 3, 8}], 3]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Answering your comment, I'll explain how I arrived at the formula. Look at the following image:

[image]

As you may see, we want the middle point of a side aligned with Pi/2. So ... what is **α**? It's obvious

> **2 α = 2 Pi/n (one side)  ->  α = Pi/n**

**Edit 2**

If you want the bottom side aligned with the x axis, add `3 Pi/2- Pi/n` instead ...

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the previous delete, I made a mistake and saw it too late

Comment: Thank you very much! 
*Im just wondering, but how did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Add Math.PI / n to the angles.

Comment: I assume you mean something like
p.addPoint((int) (100 + 50 * Math.cos((i * 2 + Math.PI/n) * Math.PI / n)), (int) (100 + 50 * Math.sin((i * 2 + Math.PI/n) * Math.PI / n)));
Well, I gave it a try, and it doesn't work, unless I've misinterpreted your answer. Care to elaborate?

Comment: You're adding (π/n)^2. Use `Math.cos((i * 2 + 1) * Math.PI / n)` instead. BTW, if this is homework you should tag it as such.

Comment: actually, I just tried it, and it only works on squares and octagons, but thats good enough for now

Comment: I works the same on all polygons, but it forces a vertical side instead of horizontal (sorry, didn't actually test it). You needed to add another π/2 for a quarter-circle rotation, as in the other answer.